# PouchDB + Ionic using WebSQL and not SQLite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed SQLite like so:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
```

And I see it in my plugins folder in IOS when I build my application.

I downloaded the SQLite.js and added it in my html after ng-cordova and before my app javascript like so:

```
<script src="js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/pouchdb-6.0.4.js"></script>
```

But when I do database calls I get this in the console:

```
db.info().then(function (result) { console.log(JSON.stringify(result); });
```

Notice it says: **`"adapter":"websql"`**

```
{"doc_count":1,"update_seq":2,"websql_encoding":"UTF-8","db_name":"DBNAME","auto_compaction":true,"adapter":"websql"}
```

Does anyone know what else I need to do? Kind of confused why its not using SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
PouchDB.plugin(cordovaSqlitePlugin);
```

Before creating/opening the database.

The tell it to use the sqlite adapter (ex.)

```
this.userdb = new PouchDB('system-user.db', { adapter: 'cordova-sqlite' });
```